# Overriding styles | JQuery

Tags: jquery, overriding

This code works fine here

http://jsfiddle.net/LH7sy/11/

It tries to find `sml(` and `)sml` in elements with the class `uppercase` and replace them with `<span style="text-transform:none">` and `</span>`

but when I try to put all of that in one file, HTML file, it just won't work !

Should I use something else instead of $(document).ready ? What is wrong ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.uppercase').each(function() {
        var end = false;
        var s = $(this).html();
        while(end == false) {
            var p1 = s.indexOf('sml(');
            var p2 = s.indexOf(')sml');
            if (p1 != -1) { /* if '(' is found in the string */
                var result = s.substring(0,p1);
                result += '<span style="text-transform:none">';
                result += s.substring(p1+4,p2);
                result += '</span>'                        
                result += s.substr(p2+4);
                s = result;
            } else {
                end = true;
            }
        }
        $(this).html(result);
    })
})
-->
</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.uppercase:hover {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <span class="uppercase">
     everything uppercase except sml(this)sml and sml(this too)sml
  </span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a reference to jQuery before your `document.ready` call:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Style should really be up in the `<head>` of the document.  You also need to ensure you're actually loading jQuery, which isn't specified in your code.